# Как правильно опубликовать домен 3-го уровня?

Tags: iis, домен, site

решил создать сайт с помощью IIS. Опубликовал домен 2го уровня без проблем. Но при обращении к домену 3-го уровня выдает ошибку 404 (HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.).
в чем может быть проблема?
у меня есть свой выделенный IP, и две виртуальные машины(они в домене), на 1 стоит домен 2го уровня а на второй хочу сделать 3й уровень. При обращении из локальной сети все работает нормально, а если подключаться через интернет то выдает ошибку.